# Not able to use the static method of a JavaFX program in another class

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a method to show a dialogue box with suitable information when called. I have created another test class to call and test the method which I have previously mentioned. When I call the method using this test class it shows some errors which I am not able to solve. Thanks in advance...

```
    package my_classes;

    import javafx.stage.*;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.*;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.layout.*;

    public class MessageBox
    {
        public static void show(String label, String button, String title, int xaxis, int yaxis)
        {
            Stage window=new Stage();
            Scene sc;
            Button btn=new Button(button);
            btn.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
            Label lbl=new Label(label);
            window.setTitle(title);
            VBox vb=new VBox(50);
            vb.getChildren().addAll(lbl,btn);
            vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            sc=new Scene(vb,xaxis,yaxis);
            window.setMaxHeight(yaxis+100);
            window.setMaxWidth(xaxis+100);
            window.setMinHeight(yaxis-100);
            window.setMinWidth(xaxis-100);
            window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            window.setScene(sc);
            window.showAndWait();
        }
    }
```

```
    package my_classes;

    public class test
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            MessageBox.show("This is a piece of text", "OK", "Test", 500, 300);
        }
    }
```

["image of the error message"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1BQs.png)

Comment: Your error states: "This operation is permitted on the event thread only;" You need to call this from the JavaFX event thread. If you called it from the start() method (available if you subclass Application), this happens automatically. You can use ``Platform.runLater(java.lang.Runnable runnable)`` to do this.

Comment: java naming conventions please .. and don't forget to work through a tutorial on javafx application basics

Comment: kleopatra - I usually override the start method, use the launch method in main method and then continue to program it. But I've done it in this way because I saw this structure in a book and I thought of trying that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the normal JavaFX application startup procedure. That means inheriting from the [Application](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) class and using the `launch()` method in order to properly initialize the JavaFX runtime.

For example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    /**
     * Initialize the application
     *
     * @param args The application arguments
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
       // Code here
    }
}
```

Please take your time to read the JavaFX documentation:
https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/

Comment: Note: Can also use `Platform#startup(Runnable)` if needed (for some reason).

Comment: I usually override the start method, use the launch method in main method and then continue to program it. But I've done it in this way because I saw this structure in a book and I thought of trying that.

Comment: Which book would that be, might I ask @Neo ? It seems to me like they've missed out on a huge chunk of actually initializing the JavaFX runtime.